# Adobe Brackets: how can I find/replace multiple lines?

Tags: search, replace, find, adobe-brackets

is there a way to find multiple lines within a project e.g.

```
<li>ABC</li>
<li>LKJ</li>
```

and replace it with: e.g.

```
<li>...</li>
<li>ABC</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>LKJ</li>
```

?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think you are asking for something similar to Sublime Text's Ctrl+D.  This lets you select the text you want to replace, then progressively select successive matches within the file.  Once all instances are selected, you are able to edit them at the same time.  Is this what you're looking for?  If so, the same can be accomplished in Brackets by selecting what you want to replace and pressing Ctrl+B until all instances you want are selected.

Comment: I need to replace these line within the whole project , not just within a file. As in Dreamweaver...

Answer (score 2):

1. Find > Replace In Files
2. Choose files
3. Set search and replace text
4. Review changes
5. Replace

http://blog.brackets.io/2014/06/27/brackets-0-41-release-replace-across-files/

Answer (score 2):

Brackets has the ability to use regex commands. There's alittle button with [.*]next the search field . Click that to activate it. So to do what you want your search field would be something like:

```
(<li>ABC</li>)(<li>LKJ</li>)
```

And your replace would be:

```
<li>...</li>$1<li>...</li><li>...</li>$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets has more powerful shortcuts to help replace any matched string.

> Ctrl + H can be used to Find and Replace Strings without Regex